# how to trigger event listener iteratively using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i want to create chrome extension that can automaticly input a text into `input` and execute the event listener from an element (it's a click-able `svg`). but i don't know how to implement it. i tried to look what was the event listener for this `svg` using chrome `inspect` but i still have no idea how it's work and how to make chrome extension as i planned. is it possible to do this? here's the search bar code. the click-able `svg` is the last one which have class `i18n-icon-search`. thank you!

```
<div class="arco-input-group i18n-ecom-select-search flex-1 arco-input-group-compact">
  <div tabindex="0" class="i18n-ecom-select arco-select arco-select-single arco-select-size-large" style="width: 122px;">
    <div class="arco-select-view">
        <input tabindex="-1" class="arco-select-view-input arco-select-hidden" value="Order ID" style="width: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
        <span class="arco-select-view-value">Order ID</span>
        <div class="arco-select-suffix">
            <div class="arco-select-arrow-icon">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="1em" height="1em">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
                        d="M3.646 6.146a.5.5 0 01.708 0L8 9.793l3.646-3.647a.5.5 0 01.708.708l-4 4a.5.5 0 01-.708 0l-4-4a.5.5 0 010-.708z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="i18n-ecom-input arco-input-group-wrapper arco-input-group-wrapper-default arco-input-has-suffix">
    <span class="arco-input-group">
        <span class="arco-input-inner-wrapper arco-input-clear-wrapper">
            <input placeholder="Search Order ID" class="arco-input arco-input-size-default" value="">
            <span class="arco-input-group-suffix">
                <svg viewBox="0 -2 20 20" width="1em" height="1em" class="i18n-icon i18n-icon-text-delete">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M17 8A7 7 0 113 8a7 7 0 0114 0zm-4.646-2.354a.5.5 0 010 .708L10.707 8l1.647 1.646a.5.5 0 01-.708.708L10 8.707l-1.646 1.647a.5.5 0 01-.708-.708L9.293 8 7.646 6.354a.5.5 0 11.708-.708L10 7.293l1.646-1.647a.5.5 0 01.708 0z"></path>
                </svg>
                <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="1em" height="1em" class="i18n-icon i18n-icon-division">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"d="M8 11.5a.5.5 0 01-.5-.5V5a.5.5 0 011 0v6a.5.5 0 01-.5.5z"></path>
                </svg>
                <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="1em" height="1em" class="i18n-icon i18n-icon-search">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M7 11a4 4 0 100-8 4 4 0 000 8zm0 1A5 5 0 107 2a5 5 0 000 10z"></path>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.354 9.646l2.5 2.5a.5.5 0 01-.708.708l-2.5-2.5.708-.708z"></path>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use dispatchEvent function : `document.querySelector('#myId').dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {}))` you will need to customize your event to your needs and change the value of the input

Answer (score 0):

Here how i do it to write to an input :

```
// write the value
document.querySelector(selector).value = value
// Dispatch the input event
document.querySelector(selector).dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {}))
```

Comment: may i know, why using event input instead of click? the svg search icon have click event, i tried using your code but it didn't work as i planned. here's my post talking about it thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/q/72180764/18986565

Comment: Well if you want to add text to an input you need to use the input event, i don't understand why you want to click on it

Comment: that's true, but i want to trigger the click event of the search bar after. so isn't it need to use dispatchEvent click?

Comment: Well you need to dispatch the click event also you can, or use .click() function

Answer (score 0):

First, get the parent div and find all input elements

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').getElementsByTagName('input')
```

this will return an array of all input elements in that div, after it
loop through that array and for each element put this to fire the input event.

```
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles:true}));
```

where 'element' is the input element of each loop iteration.

Comment: i'm planning to put the value. which i want to automaticly input, into textarea. so i will scan every line of the text area then put it into input tag of the website then call the event of the button. i did try it but, it doesn't work. i post the question here, can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72180764/18986565