# Why the value didn't set but the dispatch event run?

Tags: javascript, input, dispatchevent

i have this code to set an input then click the button. i tried run the code by removing the dispatchEvent and num is set, when i run it with the dispatchEvent it didn't set the input value but the dispatchEvent works. Should i add a delay to execute set value then dispatchEvent? or separate it? How to fix this? Thank you!

```
const inits = function(){
  const injectElement = document.createElement('div');
  injectElement.className = "my-button";
  injectElement.id = "bigBtn";
  $('body').append(injectElement);

  spn = '<span class="big-span"></span><span class="small-span">Auto Fill</span><button class="btn btn-white" id="fillBtn" type="button">Fill</button>'
  $('#bigBtn').append(spn);
}
inits();

$('#fillBtn').click(function (e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  num = 123;
  document.querySelector('input.arco-input').value = num;
  document.querySelector('.i18n-icon-search').dispatchEvent(new Event('click',{bubbles:true}));
});
```

Comment: Can you please share more code and details?

What is supposed to happen when a click event is triggered on icon search? Is icon search the correct class for the button? Add more context please

Comment: You've narrowed the example too down. What does the click listener function do?

Comment: i was making chrome extension for a website to automaticly fill the input and search the value, is there a way to see the event listener?

Comment: Open Elements tab, select an element to inspect, you can find event listeners from Event Listeners tab (in the same window where there's Styles tab).

Comment: oh it was the bubbles option, when i remove it the num is set but click event didn't run and vice versa